# Finding marginal effects for sampleSelection model

Tags: r, marginal-effects

I am estimating a gravity trade model using the `sampleSelection` package and having trouble calculating marginal effects. I would like to use the `marginaleffects` package. The model converges with results below.

The data is available [here](https://latech365-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/jjhold_office_latech_edu/Ebx3aCwH9opEncnO4wU-2m8BhZFDTB3a5WH9xo0cHhBnOw?e=F4xuq1): (I would make it smaller, but I cannot figure out how to reduce the size and keep the problem).

The model was having trouble converging so I followed the instructions to this two-step process.

```
selec_lm_1206_nums <- 
bin_1206 ~ pct_lag_1_yr_of_ukr_sunflowers + log(total_world_exports_1206) + member_wto_d + agree_pta_goods + covid_year + deaths + events + deaths * agree_pta_goods + events * agree_pta_goods

outcom_lm_1206_nums <- 
log(netweight_kg_1206) ~  pct_lag_1_yr_of_ukr_sunflowers + log(total_world_exports_1206) + member_wto_d + agree_pta_goods + covid_year + deaths + events + deaths * agree_pta_goods + events * agree_pta_goods + month_february + month_march + month_april + month_may + month_june + month_july + month_august + month_september + month_october + month_november + month_december + partner_armenia + partner_australia + partner_austria + partner_azerbaijan + partner_bangladesh + partner_belarus + partner_belgium + partner_bulgaria + partner_china + partner_czech_rep +  partner_denmark + partner_egypt + partner_estonia + partner_finland + partner_france + partner_georgia + partner_germany + partner_hungary + partner_india + partner_iraq + partner_italy + partner_lebanon + partner_morocco + partner_netherlands + partner_pakistan + partner_poland + partner_portugal + partner_rep_of_moldova + partner_romania + partner_russian_federation + partner_spain +    partner_sweden + partner_switzerland + partner_turkey + partner_united_kingdom

selec_1206_nums_2S <- selection(selection = selec_lm_1206_nums, outcome = outcom_lm_1206_nums, data = ukr_exports_analysis_sunflowers, method = "ml",maxMethod="SANN", parscale = 0.001)

selec_1206_nums <- selection(selection = selec_lm_1206_nums, outcome = outcom_lm_1206_nums, data = ukr_exports_analysis_sunflowers, method = "ml", start = coef(selec_1206_nums_2S))

summary(selec_1206_nums)

> summary(selec_1206_nums)
--------------------------------------------
Tobit 2 model (sample selection model)
Maximum Likelihood estimation
Newton-Raphson maximisation, 8 iterations
Return code 2: successive function values within tolerance limit (tol)
Log-Likelihood: -6585.88 
4194 observations (2297 censored and 1897 observed)
68 free parameters (df = 4126)
Probit selection equation:
                                 Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                     1.879e+01  4.317e+00   4.352 1.38e-05 ***
pct_lag_1_yr_of_ukr_sunflowers  2.864e-02  2.618e-03  10.938  < 2e-16 ***
log(total_world_exports_1206)  -8.678e-01  1.955e-01  -4.438 9.31e-06 ***
member_wto_d1                  -1.166e-01  5.973e-02  -1.952   0.0510 .  
agree_pta_goods1                5.668e-01  6.893e-02   8.223 2.63e-16 ***
covid_year1                     1.320e-01  7.484e-02   1.764   0.0779 .  
deaths                          4.391e-05  2.100e-04   0.209   0.8344    
events                         -3.939e-03  3.351e-03  -1.175   0.2399    
agree_pta_goods1:deaths         2.469e-04  3.932e-04   0.628   0.5301    
agree_pta_goods1:events         1.666e-03  5.520e-03   0.302   0.7627    
Outcome equation:
                                 Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                    33.9286921 10.5381573   3.220 0.001294 ** 
pct_lag_1_yr_of_ukr_sunflowers  0.0289553  0.0081910   3.535 0.000412 ***
log(total_world_exports_1206)  -1.0689663  0.4786482  -2.233 0.025582 *  
member_wto_d1                  -1.5041634  0.4674271  -3.218 0.001301 ** 
agree_pta_goods1                0.5015109  0.2095119   2.394 0.016723 *  
covid_year1                     0.2456088  0.1737226   1.414 0.157496    
deaths                          0.0013708  0.0005869   2.336 0.019560 *  
events                         -0.0376453  0.0088565  -4.251 2.18e-05 ***
month_february1                -0.0758067  0.1989450  -0.381 0.703191    
month_march1                   -0.1663013  0.1959581  -0.849 0.396121    
month_april1                    0.1921004  0.2014316   0.954 0.340304    
month_may1                     -0.0005563  0.2059650  -0.003 0.997845    
month_june1                    -0.1007850  0.2146457  -0.470 0.638708    
month_july1                    -0.1424848  0.2174332  -0.655 0.512309    
month_august1                  -0.6256302  0.2279437  -2.745 0.006083 ** 
month_september1                0.0350345  0.2076408   0.169 0.866020    
month_october1                  0.4296219  0.1991467   2.157 0.031039 *  
month_november1                 0.4897676  0.2045072   2.395 0.016671 *  
month_december1                -0.0395080  0.1948822  -0.203 0.839358    
partner_armenia1                0.6667811  0.4272304   1.561 0.118670    
partner_australia1              2.0320576  1.0742590   1.892 0.058616 .  
partner_austria1               -4.4739967  0.3911026 -11.439  < 2e-16 ***
partner_azerbaijan1             0.0777747  0.4583665   0.170 0.865272    
partner_bangladesh1             3.3733063  1.2954631   2.604 0.009249 ** 
partner_belarus1               -2.0996295  0.4959205  -4.234 2.35e-05 ***
partner_belgium1                2.2120262  0.4485863   4.931 8.50e-07 ***
partner_bulgaria1               1.7822446  0.3461572   5.149 2.75e-07 ***
partner_china1                  1.1775708  0.4552847   2.586 0.009731 ** 
partner_czech_rep1              0.4901475  0.4240523   1.156 0.247803    
partner_denmark1                0.3459561  0.3971738   0.871 0.383781    
partner_egypt1                  1.2197630  0.3712942   3.285 0.001028 ** 
partner_estonia1                0.1315394  0.3839395   0.343 0.731913    
partner_finland1                1.7183312  0.3989766   4.307 1.69e-05 ***
partner_france1                -5.1335809  0.3603393 -14.247  < 2e-16 ***
partner_georgia1                1.2181676  0.3618550   3.366 0.000768 ***
partner_germany1                2.1981464  0.3376699   6.510 8.43e-11 ***
partner_hungary1               -0.7684804  0.4972521  -1.545 0.122313    
partner_india1                  1.4954587  0.3779445   3.957 7.72e-05 ***
partner_iraq1                   0.0907309  0.4449478   0.204 0.838431    
partner_italy1                  0.4845864  0.3986407   1.216 0.224208    
partner_lebanon1               -0.2231801  0.4473566  -0.499 0.617886    
partner_morocco1                2.9440561  0.8725557   3.374 0.000748 ***
partner_netherlands1            1.6506210  0.3821066   4.320 1.60e-05 ***
partner_pakistan1               2.5107821  0.7899278   3.178 0.001491 ** 
partner_poland1                 1.6749368  0.3356626   4.990 6.29e-07 ***
partner_portugal1               1.1662223  0.5492737   2.123 0.033796 *  
partner_rep_of_moldova1         0.8918645  0.3736330   2.387 0.017031 *  
partner_romania1                1.4345824  0.3438745   4.172 3.08e-05 ***
partner_russian_federation1     2.2659206  0.4644291   4.879 1.11e-06 ***
partner_spain1                  0.2770208  0.3671673   0.754 0.450603    
partner_sweden1                 0.8975827  0.4214778   2.130 0.033263 *  
partner_switzerland1            1.9644726  0.7822877   2.511 0.012070 *  
partner_turkey1                 2.8141320  0.4212573   6.680 2.70e-11 ***
partner_united_kingdom1        -0.0482882  0.4040543  -0.120 0.904878    
agree_pta_goods1:deaths        -0.0001057  0.0009334  -0.113 0.909866    
agree_pta_goods1:events         0.0251029  0.0133068   1.886 0.059301 .  
   Error terms:
      Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
sigma  2.17716    0.08559   25.44   <2e-16 ***
rho    0.65668    0.05969   11.00   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
--------------------------------------------
```

When I attempt to find the marginal effects:

```
> mfx_s <- marginaleffects(selec_1206_trends)
Error: Unable to extract the data from model of class `selection`. This can happen in a variety of cases, such as when a `marginaleffects` package function is called from inside a user-defined function. Please supply a data frame explicitly via the `newdata` argument.
> mfx_s <- marginaleffects(selec_1206_trends, newdata = datagrid())
Error: object of type 'symbol' is not subsettable
In addition: Warning message:
Could not get model data. 
> mfx_s <- marginaleffects(selec_1206_trends, newdata = ukr_exports_analysis_sunflowers)
Error: object of type 'symbol' is not subsettable
> marginaleffects(selec_1206_nums, newdata = datagrid(newdata = ukr_exports_analysis_sunflowers))
Error: object of type 'symbol' is not subsettable
```

I am not certain what data to give it. I have seen means and medians and using the original data. I have tried giving it the original data in a couple of ways shown above. Really interestingly, if I give the marginal effects function the initial guess the function says the selection models are not supported, but the documentation says they are.

```
> marginaleffects(selec_1206_nums_2S, newdata = datagrid(newdata = ukr_exports_analysis_sunflowers))
Error: Models of class "selection" are not supported.
```

I would like to generate a conditional marginal effects plot. Any ideas?

Comment: Hard to diagnose without the data and the original model. It looks like the problem is that `marginaleffects` is having trouble finding the original data, so I would try to supply *the original data you used to fit the model** to the `newdata` argument. You can also supply the data frame in question to the `datagrid()` function, like `marginaleffects(model, newdata = datagrid(newdata = yourdataset))` If you can supply a minimal reproducible example with public data, I can help diagnose more.

Comment: Understood. I will try to figure out how to make a MRE. I tried your suggestion:
`> marginaleffects(selec_1206_nums, newdata = datagrid(newdata = ukr_exports_analysis_sunflowers))
Error: object of type 'symbol' is not subsettable`
I have had this error before in an unrelated context and it was something silly and I cannot remember what it was.

Comment: Is the data a "standard" data frame or some weird pre-processed thing?

Comment: The data has been processed substantially, but it is in a typical long panel format (i.e. each row is a month of trading data for a country and all of the other explanatory variables appropriate for the time period). Most variables are binary (factors) for fixed effects. It was assembled from csv files. did some mapping earlier and I do not think it should have kept any of the sf stuff, but I will check that.

Comment: Not spatial.
`> class(ukr_exports_analysis_sunflowers)
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"`

Comment: It may not be helpful, but your other package `modelsummary` seems to be having problems with it too. It lists several values for the estimates. `Warning: 
There are duplicate term names in the table.

The `shape` argument of the `modelsummary` function can be used to print
related terms together. The `group_map` argument can be used to reorder,
subset, and rename group identifiers. See `?modelsummary` for details.

You can find the group identifier to use in the `shape` argument by calling
`get_estimates()` on one of your models. Candidates include:`

Comment: The data must be weird if both packages fail. If you can send me a .RDS file (saved with saveRDS()) with the final data used to fit the model and a one-liner .R script to fit the model, I can take a look.

Comment: sorry, link seems expired.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the data. It helped me identify a couple bugs. The development version of the package should now be fixed. You can download it and try again. See my answer for how to download the dev version. Thanks again!

Comment: Thank you! I am going to delete the links now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original poster shared data and code with me, and it helped me identify a bug which is now fixed. In principle, installing the development versions of the `insight` and `marginaleffects` packages should solve this problem:

```r
library(remotes)
install_github("easystats/insight")
install_github("vincentarelbundock/marginaleffects")
```

Make sure you restart `R` completely. Then,

```r
library("sampleSelection")
library("marginaleffects")

data("Mroz87", package = "sampleSelection")
Mroz87$kids  <- (Mroz87$kids5 + Mroz87$kids618 > 0)
dat <- Mroz87

mod <- selection(lfp ~ age + I( age^2 ) + faminc + kids + educ,
                 wage ~ exper + I( exper^2 ) + educ + city, 
                 data = dat)
mfx <- marginaleffects(mod)

summary(mfx)
#> Average marginal effects 
#>     Term     Contrast     Effect Std. Error z value  Pr(>|z|)      2.5 %
#> 1    age        dY/dX -7.759e-03  2.901e-03  -2.675 0.0074752 -1.344e-02
#> 2 faminc        dY/dX  2.120e-06  7.637e-07   2.775 0.0055131  6.228e-07
#> 3   kids TRUE - FALSE -1.622e-01  9.040e-02  -1.794 0.0728393 -3.393e-01
#> 4   educ        dY/dX  3.556e-02  2.135e-02   1.666 0.0958117 -6.287e-03
#>       97.5 %
#> 1 -2.074e-03
#> 2  3.617e-06
#> 3  1.502e-02
#> 4  7.740e-02
#> 
#> Model type:  selection 
#> Prediction type:  response
```